# Build simple clojure webproject with leiningen and jenkins

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins, clojure, leiningen

I have a simple web project based on clojure, that just contains some markdown files in the resources folder. Previously I ran it with

```
cd my-project
lein ring server
```

and then I viewed the running project in the browser at http://localhost:port.

Now I wanted to integrate this process with jenkins so I

- created a clojure project locally (in eclipse)
- added leiningen support to my jenkins (add path to leiningen-standalone.jar in config)
- added the build step 'build project using leiningen' in the jenkins job config
- use jenkins to checkout from SCM and build the project

But then, Jenkins always complains about

```
> java -client -XX:+TieredCompilation
> -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/.lein/self-installs/clojure-1.8.0.jar 
> -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
> -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.easy=false 
> -Dleiningen.original.pwd=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/my-project/workspace
> -cp /home/.lein/self-installs/clojure-1.8.0.jar clojure.main -m leiningen.core.main install 
> 
> Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.main
> Build step 'Build project using leiningen' marked build as failure
```

I assumed, jenkins is missing the clojure.jar and it's not installing it to the .m2 repository, so I added it manually to

```
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clojure-1.8.0.jar
```

But that doesn't change anything for the build.

How to tell jenkins where to find the clojure.main? Any hints, what I am missing?

Comment: Something is not configured correctly.  It should be like this `... -cp /var/lib/jenkins/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-standalone.jar clojure.main -m leiningen.core.main uberjar` notice the leiningen jar not the clojure jar.

Comment: You are right. I tested with the clojure jar instead of leiningen jar to fix it. Changed that and added the uberjar task. The error remains: `$ java -client -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.6.1-standalone.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.easy=false -Dleiningen.original.pwd=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/leiningen-clojure-test/workspace -cp /home/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.6.1-standalone.jar clojure.main -m leiningen.core.main uberjar`

Comment: Just a thought but does the jenkins service account have permissions to `/home/.lein` I remember when I set this up I specifically placed it at `/var/lib/jenkins` and had to change owner

Comment: @Scott Ah, you name it. Sometimes it can be simple as this. Did this and everything runs smoothely. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem. I remember I had the same error but couldn't remember exactly solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr - check permissions

When you setup [leiningen+plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/leiningen+plugin) for Jenkins make sure that the service account that **jenkins** is running under is the owner and has permissions to the **leiningen-standalone.jar**

In my case I installed leiningen at `/var/lib/jenkins/.lein` which was the default for the jenkins install and changed owner to `jenkins:jenkins`

Answer (score 1):

Have you added clojure as a dependency in your project.clj?

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
```

Comment: Well, the part from the project.clj reads `:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [leiningen "2.6.1"]]`

Comment: It's unusual to have leiningen itself as a dependency.

Comment: Ok, I removed it as I just added this for debugging. Thanks.